# How to set bottom postion style for v-snackbar vuetify component in Vuejs?

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to stack multiple `v-snackbars` from the bottom. The inline style to set `bottom` property doesn't seem to affect it.

`Snackbar.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-snackbar
           v-for="(snackbar, index) in snackbars"
           :key="index"
           v-model="snackbar.visible"
           :color="snackbar.color"
           :style="{ bottom: `${index * 60 + 8}px` }"
        >
          {{ snackbar.text }}                                                                                </v-snackbar>
    <div>
</template>
...
```

`App.vue`

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <ProgressCircular />
    <Snackbar />
    <v-main>
      <transition mode="out-in" name="fade">
        <router-view />
      </transition>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "absolute" attribute.

```
<v-snackbar
  v-for="(snackbar, index) in snackbars"
  :key="index"
  v-model="snackbar.visible"
  :color="snackbar.color"
  :style="{ bottom: `${index * 60 + 8}px` }"
  absolute
  bottom
>
  {{ snackbar.text }}                                                                                
</v-snackbar>
```